# How to write a .tiff file with transparent background in python and openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, png, tiff, transparent

I have some `.png` files with transparent backgrounds, I am doing some channel alterations on the files and converting them into the `.tiff` format

```
 def convert_image(input_image_name):
    # Reading the image using imread() function
    file_name = ""
    image = cv2.imread(input_image_name)
    image[:] = (0, 0, 255)
    file_name = "converted.tiff"
    cv2.imwrite(file_name, image, [cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 5])
    return file_name
```

but I want to create `.tiff` files with transparent backgrounds, how do I achieve this in python and openCV?

Comment: If you want to read in the existing alpha channel (transparency) you need to use `image = cv2.imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` then `print(image.shape)` and you'll see it now has 4 channels - i.e. BGRA.

Comment: So how can i use this information in this context?

Comment: Load the PNG as suggested, then try writing it straight out as a TIFF and see if the alpha is preserved. Then try setting the alpha channel to 64 and write it again and see what it does `im[:,:,3] = 64`

Comment: I did that                                                                                                                 
`image = cv2.imread("D:\\Development\\Images for testing\\3.png",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imwrite('mytiff.tiff', image, [cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 5])

image = cv2.imread("mytiff.tiff",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
image[:,:,3] = 64
cv2.imwrite('mytiff2.tiff', image, [cv2.IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 5])`                     At the first conversion background is transparent, at the second conversion background is not transparent but black

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was `numpy` and `pillow`

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("3.png")
im = im.convert('RGBA')

data = np.array(im)   # "data" is a height x width x 4 numpy array
data[..., :-1]= (255, 0, 0) # Transpose back needed
im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
im2.save("mytiff.tiff")
```